# Push a custom string to current Python stack / traceback

Tags: python

How can I implement a context manager with the following API:

```
s = "this is my message"
with PushStackFrame(s):
  raise RuntimeError("something")
```

such that when RuntimeError is raised, I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 4, in <module>
    ## PushStackFrame: this is my message  ## KEY LINE
  File "foo.py", line 5, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("something")
RuntimeError: something
```

Most importantly, I want the string passed to `PushStackFrame` to be inserted *verbatim* into the stack trace, I don't want to see just the code.

One way to do this is to catch the exception on the way out of the context manager, figure out where in the traceback the context manager was called, and insert a new traceback frame, before rethrowing the exception with traceback. I'd prefer not to do this.